# Why does this scale animation jitter at the end?

Tags: html, css

I just want this image to scale down from 2 and back to normal then stop.
In my browser it jitters at the end of the animation and the image goes back to the normal size..
Any idea why it's doing this?

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/jOaWXzr) also.

```css
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image {
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 30vw;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  animation: scale 4.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation: scale 4.5s ease;
  -moz-animation: scale 4.5s ease;
  -o-animation: scale 4.5s ease;
  -ms-animation: scale 4.5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
 <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/1000/1000')"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don’t see any jitter on Safari IOS 15. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: If I understood correctly the issue is that image when goes from scale 2 to scale 1 it gives a little jerk at the end ?

I didn't see any jerk when I tested codepen in Chrome. The only jerk I am observing is when I run code in the above example.

Comment: Yeah it's doing it on Chrome for me (latest Chrome)... IOS 11.3.1. Super frustrating, oh well.

Comment: I'm also on Chrome and it didn't do anything special or disturbing at the end of the animation for me. Are you having this issue on a specific screen size, maybe ?